# How to restrict that operations will be between same object, despite being declatred as base type in Java

Tags: java, generics, inheritance

I want to write a method that gets an object of the same type as argument, but to declare it in the base class, but I don't want it to accept other object that derived from same base.

For example, I have the class Animal, and I want to write a method sonOf(Animal a), but I don't want someone to do something like that:

```
Animal bolt = new Dog();
Animal mittens = new Cat();

bolt.sonOf(mittens);
```

I think a generics is needed, but I'm not sure how to use it correctly.

Thank You.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hm. You could try, for example:

```
abstract class Animal<T extends Animal<T>> {
    abstract void sonOf(T son);
}

final class Dog extends Animal<Dog> {
    void sonOf(Dog dog) { ... }
}

final class Cat extends Animal<Cat> {
    void sonOf(Cat cat) { ... }
}
```

Then you get

```
final Cat mom = new Cat();
final Cat child = new Cat();

child.sonOf(mom);

final Dog dad = new Dog();
child.sonOf(dad);          // "The method sonOf(Cat) in the type Cat is not applicable for the arguments (Dog)"
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll use it.
though, it looks over-complicated, I thought there will be somthing simpler.

Comment: But if i now want to make a collection of Animals, dont i need to set T in the declaration of the collection?
Can i still write:
    ArrayList<Animal> pets;

Comment: Using this complicated generic type is the way to do it, even the Java API does it like this (look at the `Enum` class for example). For the list, use `List<Animal<?>>`.

Comment: This does not restrict it entirely. You can still declare `class Pig extends Animal<Cat>`